# Java +Strategy + Factory + same package = how to hide specialized classes?

Tags: java, design-patterns, package, strategy-pattern

I want to hide the specialization classes from the external classes of the same package.

Example:

```
package com.app.letter;
public interface LetterChange {
   void change();
}

public class A implements LetterChange{
   public void change(){..}
}

public class B implements LetterChange{
   public void change(){..}
}
```

To instantiate these classes I use a factory....

```
package com.app.letter;
public class LetterFactory{
   public static LetterChange getInstance(Object doesNotMatter){
   return doesNotMatter.isA() ? new A() : new B();
}
```

Note, all of them are in the same package and **I DO NOT WANT** to put the factory and the specialized classes in a sub package and change the specialization classes' constructors to default (package).

Following this example, I have a third class in the same package

```
package com.app.letter;

public class DoesNotMatterClass{
   public void situations(){       
      LetterFactory.getInstance(null); // Legal
      new A(); Illegal
      new B(); Illegal    
   }
}
```

I want to provide the A or B only by the factory LetterFactory.getInstance(doesNotMatter) which is in the same package.

Comment: It's interesting that you're worried about classes in the same package doing illegal things. It's similar in some ways to code in a class accessing the class' private members rather than passing through public methods. Usually we hide things because we don't want code to break if we change them. Are you expecting developers in the package to access A and B without them knowing the risks? Also, I think you might be able to do this with a Module in Java 9 if that feature makes it in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `A` and `B` private static classes of the factory:

```
public class LetterFactory{
   public static LetterChange getInstance(Object doesNotMatter){
       return doesNotMatter.isA() ? new A() : new B();
   }

   private static class A implements LetterChange{
      public void change(){..}
   }

   private static class B implements LetterChange{
      public void change(){..}
   }
}
```

Only the factory knows the existence of these classes and can instanciate them.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I see no reason to not allow to instantiate your classes directly. Usually, you do not care who instantiated the class, as long as you are sure it was instantiated **correctly**.

Therefore, I believe you have not one problem, but two:

1. Provide a way for **anyone** to correctly create both class `A` and class `B` manually, if required.
2. Provide a way to instantiate either `A` or `B` given some set of abstract parameters (your Factory solution).

As for the first part, the are 3 ways to instantiate classes of different complexity correctly:

1. A constructor, which has a list of all required parameters and dependencies. This can be used for simple cases pretty well.
2. A factory method. This can be used for more complex scenarios.
3. A factory class/a builder class. These are usually used for complex scenarios.

Now, whichever one you choose, by all logic it should be allowed to be public. The constructor/factory method/factory class will enforce your rules to create a proper valid instance of either `A` or `B`. And, as I mentioned before, there is no possible scenario when you should disallow creating a perfectly good and valid instance of a class.

Let's say you went with a builder class as the most complex solution. Here's how your code might look:

```
package com.app.letter.A;
public class A {
    A() { //Package visibility, we don't want anyone to create an invalid A class
        ...
    }
    ...
}

public class ABuilder {
    public void validateAndSetSomeCriticalParam(Param param) {
        ...
    }
    public A build() {
        A a = new A();
        a.setSomeCriticalParam(param);
        ...
        return a;
    }
}
```

The builder should be designed in a thought in mind, that it could not in any way produce an invalid instance of `A`. This way, you can allow the builder to be the only way of instantiating `A` and not worrying about it, because all instances it creates are always valid. You can utilize proper API on the builder or Exceptions to reach this.
Also, the builder approach is the most complex one, for some simpler scenarios you might use a bunch of public static factory methods. However the idea should remain the same - the public factory methods should ensure that they produce only valid instances of `A`.

Same stuff for B class, in other package:

```
package com.app.letter.B;
public class B {
    ...
}
public class BBuilder {
    ...
}
```

Now for the factory. Basically same thing you had, but with builders:

```
package com.app.letter;
public class LetterFactory{
    public static LetterChange getInstance(Object doesNotMatter){
        if (doesNotMatter.isA()) {
            ABuilder builder = new ABuilder();
            builder.setSomeCriticalParam(...);
            builder...
            return builder.build();
        } else {
            BBuilder builder = new BBuilder();
            builder.setSomeBSpecificParam(...);
            builder...
            return builder.build();
        }
    }
}
```

And about the usages:

```
public class DoesNotMatterClass{
    public void situations(){       
        LetterFactory.getInstance(..whatever..); // Legal
        new A(); //Illegal, as it is package protected
        new B(); //Illegal, as it is package protected
        new ABuilder(); //Legal, as ABuilder can ensure that only valid As are created
        new BBuilder(); //Legal, as BBuilder can ensure that only valid Bs are created
    }
}
```

I will add, repeating myself once again, you should only hide the parts of your system that can be abused in some ways. There is no point of hiding a class or a method if there is no way for it to be abused. Therefore, if you provide a way to correctly initialize a valid instance of `A` or `B` it should not matter to you that some other part of the system can see it or use it.

Comment: I understood your explanation and it's very useful. Thank you.
The whole matter of the question is because the architeture of my project is drawed as if packages are representing the resources (web service project) and to keep the current architeture I woudn't like to create a package just to apply the strategy or to "guarantee" that my instance is built correctly.
Example:
com.app.user (user resource)
com.app.user.address (address resource of an user)
If I create another package means a new resource (at least now).
To sum up, to keep with it, I'll rather follow the WilQu approach.

Comment: The advantage I see of hiding A and B (and using a factory) is the same as making class members private: you can change them and clients won't know what's going on (or break if they use them directly). In other words, whatever is hidden can be changed without breaking client code.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Yes, and that's when you isolate package-visible A and B  in same package with a public Factory. However, OP wanted to add more classes to that package which would not be able to access A and B. That, in my opinion, is not a proper solution as it brings very tight coupling and coincidental package-level cohesion. My solution was to rework the packaging and provide a proper public API. Solution WilQu provided is the opposite - to eliminate the public API and introduce the strongest form of coupling, which is also a reasonable solution in cases you can sacrifice flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide A and B from other packages by making them package-protected.

But that won't hide them from classes in the same package.

Since they have to be visible by the factory, but not by any other class of the same package, the only way to do that is to make them private static nested classes of the factory class.

Comment: He do not want to do that. He wants an alternative to create an specialized package.

Comment: I never suggested to create a specialized package. He might now want to make A and B private static nested class, but that's the only way to achieve the goal he wants, so...

Comment: @JB Nizet, The case is that I don't want to instantiate A & B from the same package too, only by the Factory.
But thank you for your answer

Comment: I meant specialize classes in package. I figure is the same don't you?

Comment: @Bevilaqua have you read the answer? What I suggest is to create private static nested classes of the factory (just as WilQu suggests): A and B would thus only be visible from the factory.